# How to save a highlighted html text for later use?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save the highlight text in a web page so that when the user logs back in, he gets the same highlighted text.

My approach towards it as follows:

1) get the **offset and the node details** from the selected text by using the `window.getSelection()` method.

2) Save them in a database.

3) Use the saved details and highlight the text again when the user logs back in.

After research on other sites and stack exchange I found that I can dynamically highlight a text by creating a range object which requires node and offset no as its parameter as is seen in the following code.

```
               var range = document.createRange();
               range.setStart(startNode, start_offset );  // node and offset are provided in parameters.
               range.setEnd(endNode, end_offset );
```

Now, when user selects the text, I can extract the selected text's starting and ending offset by using the `window.getSelection()` method. But I could not extract the node details.

> Now I could not figure it out that how can I extract the node details
>   and save it in a file or as a cookie so that I can highlight the same
>   text again when the user opens the browser again.

I tried to find out to my best in the internet and stack exchange but no site was giving the solution approach towards saving the node Information.

Please help me to find a solution so that this work can be useful for other people as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21587466/823942

Comment: Thanks for the link. According to the rangy.js library, the selection is saved only for the current browser session. Is there a way to save the selection in a file or cookie or database for later use?

Comment: Sure, just do some searching here on SO for AJAX and what every database you prefer.